# linux stdout pipe issues

Tags: c++, linux, perl, pipe

I have a server program just writes output log to STDOUT.
I also have another Perl shell script named "logfile" ,it will gets data from STDIN  and shows some output.

```
linux$ server |  logfile
```

at first  log-file has output ,but after a few moments it stops..
is there anyone has came across this problem?

Comment: how often do you flush stdout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`server` probably buffers its output, feeding it to the pipe in chunks. Is `server` a Perl script? Add

```
$| = 1;
```

or

```
use Handle qw( );
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

to it to disable buffering for STDOUT. (Well, the first one will disable buffering for whatever handle you have `select`ed, but that's STDOUT by default.)

Comment: What while loop? Sounds like you're looking at the wrong file. Please reread what I said, and note that I'm talking about `server`.

Comment: server is c++ program , which just use std::cout<<  for infos.

Comment: You'll have to look into how to disable buffering for that I/O library. Sorry, that's outside my area of expertise. But you should be able to find an answer using Google.

Comment: hey guys, I got it ,  while loop stops when the connection broken with mysql.